# Nested Serializers in Django rest framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

**The code**

I have these models :

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    is_child_friendly = models.BooleanField()
    free_wifi = models.BooleanField()
    parking_avilable = models.BooleanField()

class RouteOrdering(models.Model):
    route_id = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity_id = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tracks')
    day = models.IntegerField()
    order = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
```

And these Serializers:

```
class ActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Activity

class RouteOrderingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RouteOrdering
        fields = ('id','day','order','route_id','activity_id','tracks')
```

**The problem**

I want the RouteOrderingSerializer to return also the activity with the same activity_id. For this I thought I should use nested serializers.

**What I've tried**

I've tried adding a nested serializer like so:

```
activity = ActivitySerializer( read_only=True)
```

But this resulted no output in the endpoint. I know this is not the use case presented in the documentation, and this is probably why its noy working.

Ill be glad to see what code will work to get this done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you got an error when you tried the following code. I assumed it was a bug related to the `_id` ending, but everything works fine when I run it.

```
class ActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Activity

class RouteOrderingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    activity_id = ActivitySerializer( read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = RouteOrdering
        fields = ('id','day','order','route_id','activity_id','tracks')
```

While you can, I don't recommend using a name ending in `_id` for a relation in Django. The issue is that Django internally stores all foreign keys under their `<relation_name>_id`. This allows various nice things, such as setting `<object>.<relation_name>_id` to an integer id and saving the object vs setting `<object>.<relation_name>` to the entire related object (which may require a db lookup to get in the first place). The one place I find this behaviour not intuitive is in serializers, where the default is to represent the relation as `"<relation_name>": <id>` instead of `"<relation_name>_id": <id>`, though you can explicitly declare the `<relation_name>_id` field and either remove or nest the `<relation_name>` field separately.

If you rename your relations to not have the trailing `_id`, the following will work:

```
class ActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Activity

class RouteOrderingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    activity = ActivitySerializer( read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = RouteOrdering
        fields = ('id','day','order','route_id','activity','tracks')
```

(Note that declaring `route` instead of `route_id` would be more in line with the default behaviour, but less clear in my opinion)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. It didnt work, and returned view without 'activity' field showing up. other ideas?

Comment: That is very odd. Can you run it without the `activity =...` line or the `fields =...` line and post the resulting json?

Comment: here is a pastebin with the resulting json : http://pastebin.com/MKz4mDKB

Comment: Oh, I misread your models. I'm pretty sure you're never supposed to have a relation name ending in `_id`. Django stores the value internally as `<relation_name>_id` but abstracts access to the model as just <relation_name>. This can lead to confusing behavior with serializers (since unless you create a nested serializer they return `"<relation_name>": <id>` instead of `"<relation_name>_id": <id>`), but that's what Django does.

Comment: By the way, any chance there is a possibillity to keep the original 'activity' field (with the id), and to add the new field (with the activity object) in a different name?

Comment: (I assume you are talking about serializers, not the model itself). Technically yes, but I would advise that you do the opposite and simply declare both 'activity' and 'activity_id' in 'fields' (since that mimics the ORM behaviour).

If you want the id under 'activity' and the object under 'activity_object', you could declare 'activity' and 'activity_object' and change `activity = ActivitySerializer( read_only=True)` to `activity_object = ActivitySerializer( read_only=True, source='activity')`

Comment: This way doesn't really work. when creating the serializer like this : http://pastebin.com/cr8tHYJY the 'activity_object' field doesn't even show up.

Comment: You forgot the source argument. It essentially lets you rename any serializer field. In this case, you are renaming 'activity' to 'activity_object'.

Comment: So I need my source model to have two fields if I want to present two fields in the serializer? can't the serialzier 'make up' a field and show it?

Comment: No. I guess a better explanation is that you are creating the field 'activity_object' and it automatically looks for 'activity_object' on the model to populate that field. If it can't find it, it doesn't display the field. You need to tell it to look somewhere else, which is where the `source='activity'` parameter comes in. The 'activity' field on the model can be the source for as many fields as you want (as long as the fields on the serializer have different names each time).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class ActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Activity

class RouteOrderingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    activity_id = ActivitySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = RouteOrdering
        fields = ('id','day','order','route_id','activity_id')
```

Comment: I get this error: `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'collections.OrderedDict'`, probably because activity_id is suppused to be an int. any ideas?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this error. What Django/Django-Rest-Framework version are you on?